# EF 1 to many relationship always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have one to many relationship between Color and Inventory tables.

My class:
Color.cs:

```
public class Color:Base.BaseEntity
{
   public string ColorName { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<InventoryEntity.Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
}
```

Inventory.cs:

```
public class Inventory : Base.BaseEntity
{
    public int VariationId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public VariationEntity.Variation OwnerVariation { get; set; }
    public ProductEntity.Color OwnerColor { get; set; }
}
```

My context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   #region Inventory-Colors
     modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.InventoryEntity.Inventory>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.OwnerColor)
    .WithMany(t => t.Inventories)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.ColorId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   #endregion
}
```

My problem:

```
string CName = rpinventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1).OwnerColor.ColorName;
```

it always null. the code can find inventories with id = 1 but ownercolor is null.

I cannot figure out why. Is there something I am missing? I have another relationships with same way. And they work fine.

Comment: You are mixing virtual association properties (for lazy loading) and non virtual (for eager loading): this does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: so how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Test with all association properties being virtual.